# post-build step: Copy lib and headers to specific location

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm trying to find information on how to do add a `post-build` target for my static library that copies the library and its associated header files to a specific directory.

I read about `LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES` but I'm still unsure what exactly it does, since it doesnt seem to copy headers for me.

Generally I want to copy the `lib` to `$(LOCAL_PATH)/../lib` and the headers  `$(LOCAL_PATH)/../include`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following to the end of your `Android.mk`, after `include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)`:

```
all: $(LOCAL_PATH)/../lib/$(notdir $(LOCAL_BUILT_MODULE))

$(LOCAL_PATH)/../lib/$(notdir $(LOCAL_BUILT_MODULE)): $(LOCAL_BUILT_MODULE)
    cp $< $@
    cp $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/*.h $(LOCAL_PATH)/../include
```

Note that **make** requires leading <kbd>tab</kbd>, not spaces before `cp`.

The last line could be defined differently to copy all include files available to the compiler:

```
    cp $(wildcard $(LOCAL_C_INCLUDES)/*.h $(LOCAL_PATH)/../include
```

But there is no way to automatically choose which `.h` files should be copied, and which should be left alone.

Comment: that look very promising, gonna try that and report back. Thanks!